# Export Object after promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mesh

I am using "load" and "OBJloader" from loaders.gl/core and loaders.gl/obj to load a mesh to export it as a const so other module can use it, currently I am using this

```
export const myMesh = Object.freez({
     mesh : load(path_to_obj_file,OBJLoader),
     origin: [1.4,0,2.2],
     dimensions: [2,2,2],
     scale: 1
)}
```

but then I find out that I can calculate the origin and dimensions from the obj file itself without the need to put them manually (I used to calculate them from meshlab), and I can do it from the load function itself

```
load(path_to_obj_file,OBJLoader).then((obj)=>{
console.log(obj.schema.metadata.get["boundingBox"]
}
```

boundingBox would be like that [[-1.4,-1,-2],[0.6,1,-0.2]] (numbers are not accurate at all).
and I can calculate origin and dims from the boundingBox.

my question is, how can I export the const myMesh now? since I have promise, also when we write:

```
mesh : load(path_to_obj_file,OBJLoader)
```

could that cause a problem since load returns a promise ? (currently it is working correctly)

I tried:

```
export const loadMyMesh = load(path_to_obje_file,OBJLoader).then((obj) =>{
     const myMesh = Object.freez({
     mesh: obj,
     origin: calculateOrigin(obj),
     dimensions: claculateDim(obj),
     scale: 1
    });
  return myMesh
})
```

where calculateOrigin and calculateDim are functions used to get the boundingbox and calculate the origin and the dims, but that didn't work.

so any solution ?

Comment: Try `exports.x = await y()`

Comment: If the export relies on a promise for it's value, it should always export said promise. Exporting an empty object and then updating it with a value later or exporting an object with a property that has the promise *and then later replacing the promise with a value*, are both anti-patterns. Exporting an object with a promise property and leaving it as that promise is fine.

Comment: @KevinB could you  please elaborate with an example ?

Comment: @MrMythical is there an example for that?

Comment: No, it’s not an answer; it’s guidance.

Answer (score 0):

In `mesh: obj`, the value is supposed to be a Promise, so if the promise is used as a synchronization flag, it can be a problem. But generally, a promise that produces a certain value, and the value itself are equivalent when `await`ed. As in, `2 == await 2`.

One solution is to do `const myMesh = await loadmyMesh;` in other modules.

Another solution is a little more complicated, but this way, you don't have to change anything in the other modules. Just beware that `myMesh` is not frozen until the calculations are done.

```
export const myMesh = {
    scale: 1,
    mesh: load(path_to_obj_file, OBJLoader).then(obj => {
        myMesh.origin = calculateOrigin(obj);
        myMesh.dimensions = calculateDim(obj);
        Object.freeze(myMesh);
    })
};
```

Comment: myMesh.mesh will be undefined with this solution, it was so close to what I want

Comment: I forget that `myMesh.mesh` needs to be defined before the export. I fixed it, and it should work now.

Comment: I believe we can't use Object.freeze any more ..or?

Comment: I just tested, and `myMesh` is frozen after the `origin` and `dimensions` are set. We can't freeze it beforehand because `origin` and `dimensions` can't be set after the object is frozen. There will be a little gap between the times the object is imported and it is frozen, but it's still better than nothing.